# Swift request geolocation from non-view

Tags: swift, geolocation

I'm trying to get geolocation data in an arbitrary class. I'm very new to Swift, so I have no idea why this isn't working?

Any pointers?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class GeolocationPlugin:NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
  var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
  var lat: Double = 0
  var long: Double = 0

  func getLocation() {
    print("Getting location")

    // For use in foreground
    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
//    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()


    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
      print("Error while updating location " + error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
      let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
      print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    }


    self.locationManager.requestLocation()

    print("gets here")
  }
}
```

I currently see `Getting location` and then an error:

```
2017-03-26 15:42:32.634 IonicRunner[42304:5668243] *** Assertion failure in -[CLLocationManager requestLocation], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreLocationFramework_Sim/CoreLocation-2100.0.34/Framework/CoreLocation/CLLocationManager.m:865
2017-03-26 15:42:32.638 IonicRunner[42304:5668243] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Delegate must respond to locationManager:didUpdateLocations:'
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution wound up being to move the methods out of `getLocation()`, to properly activate a location in the simulator, and to move where this class was initiated from, so it wasn't immediately released as soon as `getLocation()` completes.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class GeolocationPlugin:NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
  var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
  var lat: Double = 0
  var long: Double = 0
  var cb: ((Double, Double) -> Void)? = nil

  func getLocation(callback: @escaping (Double, Double) -> Void) {
    print("Getting location")

    // For use in foreground
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    self.locationManager.requestLocation()
    self.cb = callback
  }

  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Error while updating location " + error.localizedDescription)
  }

  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    //print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")

    if( self.cb != nil) {
      self.cb!(locValue.latitude, locValue.longitude)
    }
  }
}
```